# How do I position these images under the logo when scaling down to be responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a section in the header on the right side that scales down fine with the exception of how the right block of images are moving. The images resize just fine, but once I begin to scale down, They push into the logo div and then are placed above it.

How can I position them to place under the logo and line up accordingly while staying in the header and without just turning the display to none when I reach a certain screen size?

[Here](http://jsbin.com/rajado/edit?html,css,output) is a link for the jsbin of those images/badges. The live site is in Wordpress and the code is too much to post. Maybe if you just use Firebug or the dev tools.

[This](http://gearbags.com/) is the live version of the site.

Also as a sidenote: I have the -190px margin enabled on the live site.

Here is a screenshot just for reference[image]:

Comment: For a start, you could kill the `margin: -190px`, on `.badges-container`. Then set `.badges { display: flex }` instead of `inline-block`. Then remove the `width` directive on `.badges img`. That could be a good place to begin.

Comment: If i do that it throws everything under the logo div and then the images aren't responsive anymore. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/KJGVgoV.png)

Comment: oops. forgot to mention changing the parent `div.table-row` of `.badges-container` to `display: flex` as well. There are still some collisions at smaller sizes, but the vertical stuff is no problem any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. I added a separate media query like so:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {

    .badges-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px

    }

    .badges img {
     width: 19%;
}
```